# How to write a LocalDate list to a file in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a LocalDate list to an output file, i've got `List<LocalDate> fechas` but when i try this code:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 
        for(LocalDate str: fechas) {
          writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
```

it doesn't compile

Comment: Are you assuming that because you named the `LocalDate` variable `str` that it's a `String`?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

`write` takes a `String` - you'll have to convert your `LocalDate` to a stirng:

```
for (LocalDate fecha: fechas) {
    writer.write(fecha.toString());
}
```